Tkinter Python - Update a label from an instance method goes to segmentation fault
I'm trying to update a Label with a method that is called via a scheduler process, but when i try to configure the label, the app crashes with a segmentation fault
This is my script
class Gui():
    def __init__(self):
        app = Tk()
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.title("Title")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{700}")

        self.sidebar_frame = Frame(self)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid()
        self.my_label = Label(self.sidebar_frame)
        self.my_label.grid()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_schedule, daemon=True)
        thread.start()

    def start_schedule(self):
        schedule.every(30).seconds.do(lambda: self.update_label())

    def update_label(self):
        self.my_label=configure(text="Custom Text")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()

I tried to call the method inside the class, using the self but i keep getting the error of segmentation fault

Without seeing what schedule is doing, it's hard to say what the exact issue is, but I'd bet it has something to do with that. Generally, if you want to perform periodic function calls in a tkinter app, you should use the built-in after method. Performing GUI updates from a separate thread is also likely to cause some problems - generally all UI code should be handled in the main thread.

sorry @JRiggles i just forgot to add, they are put via grid method, it was my mistake not to add them

and schedule is a pip package https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable

Is there a particular reason you want to use that module? And have you tried using it in the main thread?

Here's a working example that updates the text of the Label widget to a random number every 3 seconds. It demonstrates how to handle this using tkinter's after method rather than relying on threading and other modules.
I've also fixed the issue preventing the Frame and Label from appearing by passing them both to pack(), and I fixed the typo in self.my_label.configure
from tkinter import *
from random import randint  # for demonstration purposes


class Gui(Tk):  # inherit from Tk in your main app class
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()  # initialize Tk (your inherited superclass)
        self.initialize_user_interface()
        self.update_label()  # begin label updates
        # if you'd rather start the label updates after a delay, do this instead:
        # self.after(30_000, self.update_label)
        # you can set whatever delay you like here

    def initialize_user_interface(self) -> None:
        self.title("Title")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{700}")

        self.sidebar_frame = Frame(self)
        self.sidebar_frame.pack()
        self.my_label = Label(self.sidebar_frame)
        self.my_label.pack()

    def update_label(self) -> None:
        """Set the label to a random value for demonstration"""
        self.my_label.configure(text=randint(0, 100))
        # repeat this function after however many mS
        self.after(3000, self.update_label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()

As an aside, you generally want to avoid "star" imports, like from tkinter import * because they can lead to a problem called "namespace pollution" (think about what would happen if some other module you were using also had a class named Label). Typically, you'll see import tkinter as tk, and any related classes are then instantiated with tk as a prefix like tk.Label, tk.Button, etc.

Thanks a lot, it works like a charm, now i have clearly understood how tkinter works

Glad I could help! Happy coding
